# Nested dicts and lists / glom lib python

Tags: json, nested-lists, glom

I am trying to access deep-nested lists and dictionaries. I am experimenting with the glom library however my Third_KV key doesn't work on the below JSON object when trying to retrieve the "Country"

```
from glom import glom

target = {
    "Result": {
        "Topics": [
            {
                "A": "abc",
                "D": 0,
                "Questions": [
                    {
                        "E": "jklm",
                        "P": "dsfs",
                        "Answers": [
                            {
                                "first": "string",
                                "second": "string",
                                "Country": "CH"
                            },
                            {
                                "first": "string",
                                "second": "string",
                                "Country": "NL"
                            }

                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}

path = {
    "First_KV": ("Result.Topics", ["Questions"]),
    "Second_KV": ("Result.Topics", [("Questions", ["Answers"])]),
    "Third_KV": ("Result.Topics", [("Questions", "Answers", ["Country"])])
}
countries = glom(target, path["Third_KV"])
```

Answer (score 2):

Not very clear what final json/array/structure you want, but without relying on any library, can you not use simple map() e.g.

```js
const jsonTest = {
  "Result": {
    "Topics": [{
      "A": "abc",
      "D": 0,
      "Questions": [{
        "E": "jklm",
        "P": "dsfs",
        "Answers": [{
            "first": "CHfirstCountry",
            "second": "CHsecondCountry",
            "Country": "CH"
          },
          {
            "first": "NLfirstCountry",
            "second": "NLsecondCountry",
            "Country": "NL"
          }
        ]
      }]
    }]
  }
};

const AnswersArray = jsonTest.Result.Topics[0].Questions[0].Answers;

let dictPerCountry = new Object();

AnswersArray.map((eachElement) => {
  dictPerCountry[eachElement.Country] = [eachElement.first, eachElement.second];
});

console.log({
  dictPerCountry
});
```

dictPerCountry will look like so:

```
{
  "dictPerCountry": {
    "CH": [
      "CHfirstCountry",
      "CHsecondCountry"
    ],
    "NL": [
      "NLfirstCountry",
      "NLsecondCountry"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Answers are of "list" type too and you are missing its square brackets. check below pattern to get the country

```
pattern = ('Result.Topics', [('Questions', [('Answers', ['Country'])])])
```

So you need to change your dictionary "path" to be

```
path = {
    "First_KV": ("Result.Topics", ["Questions"]),
    "Second_KV": ("Result.Topics", [("Questions", ["Answers"])]),
    "Third_KV": ('Result.Topics', [('Questions', [('Answers', ['Country'])])])
}
```